# How to see total net amount in membership report

Tags: civireport, 4.6.8

For example, with the built in report "Contribution and Membership Details" it will total the contributions at the bottom. But this is not the net amount. How would we get the report totals at the bottom to show contribution total, fees and net? We have people still using excel to do work that I thought CivCRM would handle, and I want to get them off of excel.

Comment: Have you tried the Extended Reports extension? I don't know off the top of my head if it includes this, but it's worth checking: https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport